# Sum cells until adjacent cell is not blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have this example:

[image: Excel Data]

I am looking for the formula to **sum all of the prices for the items bought for each individual customer** into the "Total price" column. The price of their total order is the sum of items until the next customer name shows up.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(C2="","",SUM($B2:B$11)-SUM(D3:D$11))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

In the formula, replace the ***11*** with some value that is **below** the actual data.